# Docker map port is invalid

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I followed the tutorial to compile the project's image file with gradle and type it into docker. At the same time, the image is run and the virtual port is mapped to port 8761. However, my host accesses port 8761 and cannot connect. At the same time, I start the project locally and the host 8761 can be used.

I modified the dependent jdk8 image and added EXPOSE to the dockerfile.

Below are the configuration files and the docker run command：

```
FROM gmaslowski/jdk
VOLUME /tmp
ADD his-eureka-server-one-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
#RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8760

docker run -d -t -p 127.0.0.1:8760:8760 com.anhuishangjue/his-eureka- 
server-one:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I want the host's 127.0.0.1:8760 to be able to access the eureka registry, but he told me to deny access

Comment: below are docker  show :CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
1cb549769c67        com.anhuishangjue/his-eureka-server-one:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   "java -Djava.securit…"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        127.0.0.1:8760->8760/tcp   flamboyant_montalcini

Comment: but i can't access it by 127.0.0.1:8760